# ZFS on Linux: Setting up NFS on Ubuntu 14.04 with OS X Mavericks Client

Tags: mount, macosx, nfs, zfs

I have a working zpool and dataset set on my home server. I want to setup NFS to access ZFS over my home network on my Mac.

On the Ubuntu side, I have...

- `# apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`
- `# zfs set sharenfs=rw=@192.168.0.0/24,insecure tank/documents`

  - should allow 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255
  - insecure is needed so the mac connects on ports bigger than 1024
- `# zfs share tank/documents`
- `# service nfs-kernel-server start`

  - commented out `&& grep -q '^[[:space:]]*[^#]*/' $export_files` in `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server` because I can't start the server with an empty `/etc/exports/` file
- `# showmount -e` to verify directory is mounted

The output of `showmount -e` is this.

`Export list for ubuntu1404:
/tank/documents *`

On the Mac side, I have...

- `$ rpcinfo -p 192.168.0.3` to verify NFS is visible on the network
- `$ mount -t nfs 192.168.0.3:/tank/documents /Users/me/Remote`

This last step is where I'm stuck. I keep getting "Operation not permitted".

I've been reading around, but I've only found old tutorials that use NFS Mounts from Disk Utility. Does anyone have any up-to-date tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

I must have the `mount` syntax wrong. I tried connecting in Finder and it worked!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mounting requires administrative privileges. Try using `sudo` like this:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.3:/tank/documents /Users/me/Remote
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question though, "Operation not permitted" is what you will see when there is already a mount attached to the named folder "/Users/me/Remote"

Using the Finder instead works fine, because it will instead mount the remote under /Volumes and not introduce that conflict.